# JQuery select all where arbitrary parent has class X

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out a jquery selector where I can grab all DOM elements with name A, that ALSO have a grandparent with class X. Here's an example HTML, I will have many of these

```html
<div class="interface_controlgroup">
    <div class="form-switch me-3">
        <input name="layout[]" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- note some inputs will have "d-none" on the grandparent -->
<div class="interface_controlgroup d-none">
    <div class="form-switch me-3">
        <input name="layout[]" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
    </div>
</div>

...
<!-- repeated -->
```

Now I would like to select all inputs, as well as all inputs where the grandparent has `d-none`

```js
let all_inputs = $('input[name=layout\\[\\]]');

//cannot use this because the entire section may be hidden when this is run
let hidden_inputs = $('input[name=layout\\[\\]]:hidden');

//I need something more like
let hidden_inputs = $('input[name=ide_layout_std\\[\\]]'.parent().parent()".d-none");
```

I am looking for a solution that allows me to only select when the parent's parent has a certain class, but I don't know how to create this match. I also can't rely on `":hidden"` in the jquery selector because the entire section/page may be hidden when this javascript is running.

Using JQuery 3.6 and Bootstrap 5

Comment: `.X > * > input[name=A]`

Comment: @Barmar this worked, thank you! :) would you mind putting your comment as an answer so I can accept it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `x > y` child selector to solve this. `x > * > z` matches `z` with a grandparent `x` (the parent in the middle can be anything).

```
let hidden_inputs = $('.d-none > * > input[name=ide_layout_std\\[\\]]:hidden');
```